# \lesssim (and some others) not working

Tags: symbols, amsmath, math-operators

I'm writing a latex document and trying to use `\lesssim` (listed for example in here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula#Relations ) in the text like this: `$a \lesssim b$`. However, after rendering the document with `pdflatex`, the symbol does not show up. I have included the amsmath package with
`\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}`.

Most of the similar symbols, like `\leq` or `\ll` work just fine. However, for example `\gtrsim` and `\lessapprox` don't work either.

How do I solve this? Do I need to include some other packages to get those symbols to work?

Comment: You need `amssymb`.

Comment: @Echows Take a look at ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of the site.